# Windows 8 and Windows 7 UEFI

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, windows-8-preview, uefi

I have Windows 7 x64 SP1 installed on my Asus P8Z68-V LX board through UEFI (on a GPT HDD).

I wanna install Windows 8 on the partition I made for it. But I don't have a DVD or USB drive so I extracted the system files from 'install.wim' from `%windowsdeveloperpreviewdvdiso%\sources` (btw., this is a way to do a manual install without having to install from media).

How do I set Windows 8 to have an option in the Windows 7 UEFI BCD/BOOTMGR?